# Django Rest - TemplateDoesNotExist: How to solve it?

Tags: python, django, templates, exception, django-rest-framework

Before anyone asks, I've checked a lot of answers, and 'rest_framework' is listed on my Installed Apps. I have created a new venv and installed all dependencies on it again and still the same error.
When I try the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin I get the error template TemplateDoesNotExist at /Admin.  When I try any endpoint of my API I get the same error.

I'm a bit confused because this project was running on my computer 1 month ago, but I got a problem in my computer and had to format. When I cloned the project again, got this error.

I'm going to list some of my settings about directory folder, I'm having a bad feeling about it.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]
```

Folders structure is:

```
Appapi/
   movies/
     settings.py
     urls.py
     wsgi.py
   imdb/
     migrations/
          migrationsfiles....
     models.py
     views.py
     serializers.py
     ...
   venv/
manage.py
README.md
requirements.txt
```

And some other files, like gitignore, procfile, etc.

Some of the errors traceback:
    django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: index.html

```
line 47, in select_template
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
```

Edit:
Django version 2.1;
I don't have a templates directory, I'm using rest-framework to make an API, so I'm not dealing with html, css and js with Django.

Comment: have you check the versions that you were initially installed prior to formating. what django version are currently working with.....

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the place of the template directory. if the templates directory in the Appapi/ or in each app's directory.

Django Version ?

I have suggest some changes in **settings.py** file.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),)
```

add a directory **templates** in every app

```
Appapi/
   movies/
     settings.py
     urls.py
     wsgi.py
   imdb/
     templates/
     migrations/
          migrationsfiles....
     models.py
     views.py
     serializers.py
     ...
   venv/
manage.py
README.md
requirements.txt
```

may be you can check resetting the migrations may help you..

Comment: Django version 2.1; I just made the changes you suggested and still same error.